# Win10 - screen saver: Photos are not centered on screen, cut off

Tags: windows-10

Win10, new Dell XPS 13 laptop. All Windows and Dell updates applied.

I set up a slide show (see attached). The show works,but the photos are not centered vertically. In fact, they are positioned as if the display was much taller than it actually is, so the top half of the photos are cut off.

Yuck!

I believe the problem is a bug due to the fact that I have two external displays. (I would prefer to show the slide show on one of the larger external displays, but don't see how to do that.)

How do I get the display that does work (the internal, laptop display) to at least show the photos properly and not cut off?

Displays are: 1920X1080 (laptop) 3840X2160 - 27" external 1920X1080 - projector –

Problem is observed whether or not the projector is attached.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the photos at the same px size in height and width as the resolution your display is set to? If you have square photos for example, the top and bottom will be cropped from view. If your display is set to 1920x1080 for example, having photos at those pixel height and width or even 3840x2160 will definitely fit properly. If you have 800x600 you will have problems

Comment: If Windows' built in screensaver is too simple you may need to install a third party one

Comment: @ChrisRogers That doesn't make sense. There is tons of black unused space on the screen below the pic.  If scaling was the issue, it should be cut off top and bottom, but they are only cut off on the bottom.

Comment: @golimar For now I just want to get the win native feature to work.  I would strongly prefer ability to set different pics on each display (there are three total). I looked at displayfusion, but it creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: What's the pixel dimensions of the 2 screens?

Comment: @golimar 1920X1080 (laptop)
3840X2160 - 27" external
1920X1080 - projector

Comment: how are they positioned in "customize your display"?

Comment: @golimar OP enhanced to address your question. Thx!